# (Cycles only) Motion blur is not working in cycles but is working in Eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, blur, motion-blur

I have an issue with motion blur in cycles. I imported this alembic file from houdini and tried to render it with cycles but the motion blur isnt working. I  have attached the screenshot of motion blur settings below.

[image: Cycles render]

But the motion blur in EEVEE is working flawlessly

[image: Eevee render]

Heres the motion blur settings in Cycles

[image: Cycles Motion blur settings]

Can someone please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me, I fixed it by deleting **velocity attribute** and changing **Vel unit** to **Frame**.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to press ctrl + Enter to render it out. apparently the velocity blur isn't visible for viewport render, you have to "render image" or render to disk for it to work.

Also I left it at "frame" instead of "seconds". I left deformation blur "on" on the object level in blender and also left the steps at "1".
Mine was a vellum simulation in Houdini with consistent point count.

[image]